# Cannot login to WSS 3.0 site using forms authentication

Tags: sharepoint, forms-authentication, wss-3.0

A changed Windows authentication to Forms authentication. Using the following [example](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/windows-forms/configuring-forms-authentication-in-sharepoint-2007/).

I added a user with Web Site Administration Tool. Finally I added this user as Site Collection Administrators and the user is recognized by SharePoint. Happy with that is started my WSS site in the browser but when I try to Sign in using this sign in form it is not working. Returns to this form after the submit **(//spvm:100/_layouts/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f_layouts%2fAuthenticate.aspx%3fSource%3d%252f&Source=%2f)**

I have been scanning my Eventviewer but no succes for any comment what tells me what I am doing wrong. Maybe some of you guys can help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Once you are redirected to this page, try navigating to http://spvm:100. Sometime I get this kind of case where I move make to the root, then it works. I really didnt know the reason why sometime it behaves like that.

Comment: Of course I tried but no solution. Thanx anyway. Still do not have a clue??

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I found that something was wrong with my browser's settings. I tried to log in with another browser (Firefox) and that worked for me. 
I don't know yet what was wrong with my IE7's settings, on another machine I could log in to a forms auth site without any problem.